# Как открыть Excel файл?

Tags: c#, .net

Как просто открыть excel файл без переноса в dataGriedview(Мне просто надо открыть уже созданный файл через код)

Comment: вы можете использовать библиотеки для открытия Excel файлов. Библиотека зависит от верси Excel файла - например epplus

Comment: Мне просто надо отобразить  чтобы открылся сам excel  и файл который был уже создан

Comment: Спасибо разобрался как

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте через `Process.Start(@"path");`

Comment: Спасибо разобрался